# JPA 2.0 LEFT JOIN induces INNER JOIN

Tags: jpa-2.0, left-join

I have a ClassRoom class with a name field, and a Student class with a ClassRoom field. Not all students have a classroom.
I want a list of all students with their classroom name (or an empty string if no classroom). Using this JPQL query :

```
Select s.name, s.classRoom.name from Student s LEFT JOIN s.classRoom
```

The problem is that this returns only students with a classroom. The right generated SQL should be

```
Select s.name, c.name from student s left join classroom c on c.id=s.classroomid
```

Which returns all students, but the s.classRoom.name construct seems to force an inner join in the generated SQL.

Comment: Can we see your code / annotations etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a chained expression like `s.classRoom.name` generates an inner join. You need to assign an alias to the left joined entity and use that alias:

```
select s.name, c.name from Student s left join s.classRoom c
```